# How to combine arrays of different size into a single cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, dwt

I am working on DWT in MATLAB, and I want to decompose a 1-D input vector into three levels. The output of the DWT is:

```
w =

  1×4 cell array

    [32×1 double]    [16×1 double]    [8×1 double]    [8×1 double]
```

I have processed each coefficient separately:

```
a = w{1}; b = w{2}; c = w{3};  d = w{4};
```

I want to combine `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` to get the same as `w`. I have tried `mat2cell` and `w = (a; b;c;d)` but I am not getting the same as `w`. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to put `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` back into a cell array (like `w` that you took them from), you just need to use [curly braces](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html):

```
w = {a, b, c, d};
```